# How do I show adsense on just only pages which are over 2400px height?

Tags: jquery, height, document, adsense

I'd like to get information of page height then put adsense on only over 2400px pages. If you give me any clue, would be appreciated!

```
<script>
var height = $(document).height();
if (document > 2400 ) {
echo '<!--adsense code-->'; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong variable to compare the height value. you should use condition `height>2400` instead of `document > 2400`:

```
var height = $(document).height();
if (height > 2400 ) {
  echo '<!--adsense code-->'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But still it doesn't work :'(
Is that ok if I put this kind of adsense below in ''? I'm very novice so, please pardon me...

<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-region="xxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>